# Test express router with mocha

Tags: javascript, express, mocha.js, router

I hit against a strange behaviour about routing in express (node.js).

I was trying to test an api.

the server mounts:

```
app.use("/", productRouter);
app.use("/", testRouter);

productRouter.post("/products", ...);
testRouter.post("/test", ...);
```

if i `POST` to:

```
http://localhost:MYPORT/test
http://localhost:MYPORT/products
```

everything works fine.

But if i run this mocha test:

```
const app = require("../src/index");

describe(" ====== Test for argumentMiddleware: a factory to check request arguments ======", () => {
  describe("requiredArgument middleware", () => {
    it("it should return error if requiredArgument is not in the body of request:", done => {
      let requestBody = {
        argument: "product"
      };
      chai
        .request(app)
        .post("/test")
        .send(requestBody)
        .end((err: Error, res: any) => {
          res.should.have.status(400);
          console.log(err.message);
          done();
        });
    });
    it.skip("it should pass if requiredArgument is in the body of request: ", done => {
      let requestBody = {
        requiredArgument: "product"
      };
      chai
        .request(app)
        .post("/test")
        .send(requestBody)
        .end((err: Error, res: any) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

i'm sure it do `POST` against `/products` instead of `/test`, i have a `console.log` inside `/products` that gets executed. Why is it routed to that endpoint, it happens just because it is declared first ?

Answer (score 0):

This part looks strange:

```
app.use("/", productRouter);
app.use("/", testRouter);
```

What happens if you change up the `("/")` portion for testRouter and possibly make it like so:

`app.use(testRouter);`

or

`app.use("/api", testRouter);`